# Piping createElement and appendChild in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, appendchild, createelement

Can someone please explain to me, why

```
var Node = document.createElement("testing");
var Parent = document.createElement("testingOne")
Parent.appendChild(document.createElement("hi"));
Node.appendChild(Parent);
```

produces a different result from

```
var Node = document.createElement("testing");
var Parent = document.createElement("testingOne")
    .appendChild(document.createElement("hi"));
Node.appendChild(Parent);
```

In the second snippet the element testingOne doesn't even get included. Why does the piping do this?

Comment: appendChild returns the new child, not the container. this makes it easy to do stuff like myKid=div.appendChild(document.createElement("span"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example will result in

```
<testing><testingone><hi></hi></testingone></testing>
```

`Parent` will contain the `testingOne` and the `hi` element will be appended to it.

While the second example will result in

```
<testing><hi></hi></testing>
```

Because `Parent` will contain the `hi` element, which is returned by the `appendChild` method.